# countably-infinite-index subgroup of a strongly complete profinite group

Tags: topological-groups

If $H$ is a strongly complete profinite group and $K$ is a dense countably-infinite-index subgroup, then I'm assuming a proper finite-index subgroup of $K$ could still be dense in $H$. Is there any known way of giving specific examples of dense countably-infinite-index subgroups of strongly complete profinite groups, or is there any known way of proving that what I describe is indeed possible?

Comment: What does 'strongly complete' mean?

Comment: @hjrw, I think it means all finite index subgroups are open